# Why does g++ accept a reference type with missing underlying type?

Tags: c++, c++11, g++

I was meaning to add a copy constructor to a class but forgot to add the type. g++ 5.4.0 compiled the class successfully.

Here's a minimal program that g++ 5.4.0 compiles and builds successfully.

```
struct Foo
{ 
   Foo(const&) {}
   Foo() {}
};

int main()
{
   Foo f1;
   Foo f2 = f1;
}
```

Why does g++ not report `Foo(const&) {}` as an error?

Comment: I was thinking maybe implicit int but [I can't reproduce on Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Ezv3GWQbAGyis4ev) please provide a live example.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour, ideone.com does not allow me to pick a compiler version. Any pointers on sites that allow you to do that?

Comment: Yes, the link in my comment goes to Wandbox which does.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour That's strange indeed. There must be something else in my installation. Here's an image of the terminal that shows what I posted. https://imgur.com/5BIGluy.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a defect in my installation of g++ 5.4.0.

It fails to compile using g++ 6.3 at https://ideone.com/D0vGrw.

I have used the same block of code.

```
struct Foo
{ 
   Foo(const&) {}
   Foo() {}
};

int main()
{
   Foo f1;
   Foo f2 = f1;
}
```

It also fails to compile using g++ 5.4.0 at [Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Ezv3GWQbAGyis4ev).